# Execute sh script with parameters

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have self-writed sh script, which contains contruction like "cd directory"

It is successfully running through terminal

```
. /path/to/script.sh param1 param2
```

I want to run this script through PHP

```
shell_exec('. /path/to/script.sh param1 param2');

shell_exec('. /path/to/script.sh "param1" "param2"');
```

not running correctly

```
shell_exec('/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh param1 param2');
```

running, but directory changing is not working

Please, help. Thank you in advance

Comment: You'd better use full path instead of using `~` as HOME is different among users.

Comment: You know that you have more than one difference between the commands you're running, right?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Off course

Comment: in `cd directory`, is `directory` a relative path or an absolute one?

Comment: @geomagas I tried both variants

Answer (score 5):

You're starting your command with `.` - that will be interpreted as shell-source command, which is not what you want, obviously. Instead specify full path and do like:

```
$result = shell_exec('/bin/bash /full/path/to/script.sh param1 param2');
//var_dump($result);
```

-also, make sure your php user have permission to execute your sh-script and that PHP can use functions like `exec()` (they could be disabled by configuration)

Comment: Yeah, script is successfully running, but constructions like "cd my_directory" is not working

Comment: What do you want with that `cd`? What is happening in your script? Why are you not able to use full path inside script instead of doing `cd`?

Comment: `cd_one (cd_one is function in my bash_profile)`
`executing some routine operations`
`cd_two (cd_two is function in my bash_profile)`
`executing some routine operations`

Comment: cd_one in bash_profile is just `cd first_directory` and cd_two is `cd second_directory`

Comment: Replace your aliases to direct command calls. Also try to use full paths (i.e. get rid of `cd` at all - normally, its better to avoid them since they cause less-readable code)

Comment: I tried it before, I tried it just now. It not helps, directory changing does not occur

Comment: Did you try do it without `cd`? I.e. rather than doing `cd command_dir` and then `some_command` do `/path/to/command_dir/some_command` ? Also to make `cd` working you need php user have `x` permissions (execute) on that directory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use quotes to send arguments, try this :

```
$command_result = shell_exec('script.sh "'.$param1.'" "'.$param2."');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

`shell_exec('./path/to/script.sh param1 param2');`

instead of

`shell_exec('. /path/to/script.sh param1 param2');`

...and make sure your **shell script have executable permission for user who is running your script.**

Answer (score 0):

This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode. Check your php.ini file and make sure safe mode is turned off and it's not in 'disable_functions'.

Answer (score 0):

Aviod:

1. Using the `.` notation, which would not work outside a bash shell. Use `/bin/bash <yourscript>` instead.
2. Trying to `cd` to relative paths, as this confines the script's execution to be done from a specific location only
3. Referencing (or implying) `.bash_profile` resources, as `.bash_profile` is executed only for login shells. If applicable, use `.bashrc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `escapeshellarg` to escape parameters instead of just adding quotes. `escapeshellarg` would escape all pram chars not allowed in shell.